# REDIS BGSAVE Assertion failed, terminated by signal 6. (macos / python)

Tags: python, database, macos, redis, redistimeseries

Fairly new to Redis (3days, ha) all working fine in gereral but getting this error.

````
              _._                                                  
           _.-``__ ''-._                                             
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 5.0.7 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._                                   
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 53149
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io        
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |                                  
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'                                       
          `-._        _.-'                                           
              `-.__.-'                                               

53149:M 18 Jan 2020 21:02:34.415 # Server initialized
53149:M 18 Jan 2020 21:02:34.426 * Module 'timeseries' loaded from /Users/ash/RedisTimeSeries/bin/macosx-x64-release/redistimeseries.so
53149:M 18 Jan 2020 21:02:35.238 * DB loaded from disk: 0.812 seconds
53149:M 18 Jan 2020 21:02:35.238 * Ready to accept connections
53149:M 18 Jan 2020 21:11:40.475 * Background saving started by pid 53691
Assertion failed: (leading + blocksize <= BINW), function readV, file gorilla.c, line 432.
53149:M 18 Jan 2020 21:11:40.630 # Background saving terminated by signal 6
````

I have already changed the location of the rdb file to a writable location as per answers to previous questions that I have read on Stackoverflow.

In fact my script successfully executes BGSAVE , repeatedly, for a time, and then at *some-point* it starts throwing the above error.

I restarted the server, *just to 'see'*, hence the code snippet above is not showing the successful attempts. But you can see `DB loaded from disk` as an indicator of this.

Any help with this directly, or, further reading on helpful topics related to this is appreciated.

Thankyou

Comment: How's your disk? Is `df` OK?

Comment: Disk should be fine. That’s said, what is df?

Comment: `df` is the command you need to replace the “should be” in your answer with “is”: `man df` → `display free disk space` (Wikipedia says it stands for “disk free”)

Comment: ah,  is this system wide.. showing me Filesystem.. %Used etc?

Comment: of course. Why don't you do a `man df`?

Comment: All volumes where my projects are as well as the location of the .rdb file is have tons of space.
```
devfs                    100%
map -hosts           100% 
map auto_home   100%   

although i'm not entirely sure what they are, or if they are related?

Comment: two seconds on google tells me they are just mounting locations/unrelated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206214/discussion-between-ashley-reid-and-walter-tross).

Comment: This may be related: https://github.com/RedisTimeSeries/RedisTimeSeries/issues/304

Comment: Ahh yes. I am using RedisTimeSeries. Will follow over there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. [Two issues](https://github.com/RedisTimeSeries/RedisTimeSeries/issues/304) were open for it within the last few days.

[A PR was published](https://github.com/RedisTimeSeries/RedisTimeSeries/pull/307) and it will be merged soon.

Thank you for the input.

Comment: PR is now merged and will be part of v1.2.1